# a integrale equal to a minimum

Tags: real-analysis

Show that: $\frac{1}{2}\int_{\textbf{R}}(\textbf{1}_{|x|\leq 1} -\textbf{1}_{|x+t|\leq 1})^2dx = \min(2;|t|)$  where $t\in \textbf{R}$

Some help would be appreciated

Comment: Try drawing a picture of the regions $|x|\leq 1$ and $|x+t| \leq 1$. See what happens when $|t| = 0, 1, 2$ for instance.

Comment: $\textbf{1}_{|x|\leq 1}\textbf{1}_{|x+t|\leq 1}=\textbf{1}_{|x|\leq \alpha}$ with $\alpha=\min(1;1+|t|)$ hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $(1_A-1_B)^2=|1_A-1_B| = 1_{A\triangle B}$ where $A\triangle B$ is the symmetric difference. The intervals $[-1,1]$ and $[-t-1,-t+1]$

- are disjoint if $|t|> 2$
- have overlap of size $2-|t|$ if $|t|\le 2$.

Therefore, the length of their symmetric difference is $2$ minus the overlap (counted twice). This is

- $4$  if $|t|> 2$
- $4-2( 2-|t|)$ if $|t|\le 2$.

Conclusion follows.